# Invalid postback error: Webforms for marketers

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

we are using Webforms for marketers for our landing page forms and event forms.
But, we keep getting this generic error:

Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback

i know it is might happen when some one is trying to embed some characters and posting the data, because of the event validation is enabled, it asp.net identifies these character, wil raise this error.

But, we are receiving a lot. does it mean that many times some invalid charactes entered.

could you please let me know if there are techniques to identify this error.? we are afraid our forms data is not getting posted.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably some bots try to send links through your form using  tags (which doesn't pass event validation).

You can check what values where sent using the form using e.g:

```cs
protected override NameValueCollection DeterminePostBackMode()
{
    try
    {
        return base.DeterminePostBackMode();
    }
    catch(HttpRequestValidationException exc)
    {
        string formValues = String.Empty;
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            formValues += key + "=" + Request.Form[key] + "\n";
        }
        Log("HttpRequestValidationException for form values:\n" + formValues);
        throw exc;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

In some cases adding `requestValidationMode="2.0"` to `<httpRuntime ..>` tag in **web.config** may help.